# Robotframework: How to deal with Dynamic content via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, robotframework, frames

Currently I am trying to deal with dynamic content that is being added via a JavaScript Method. I wish to retrieve which content actually is being dynamically displayed, to check it via RobotFramework.

The frame that is written into is defined as:

```
 <frame src="/root/paperform/blank.htm" name="paperform" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="" framespacing="0">
```

Now, one of several methods might be called, for example the following:
`<form name="goNoPluginForm" action="/servlet/PFServlet" method="POST" target="paperform">
   <input type="hidden" name="template" value="paperform/error/noPlugin.htm">
</form>`

The posted error is what I would like to retrieve. I tried to use the "Page Should Contain" and the "Page Should Contain Element" Keywords, which both did not bring the correct result. I do have the feeling on this keywords, that they do only check the initial web source code.

Now, how could I check which error message has been posted into the frame?

I select the Frame via the "Select Frame" Keyword already, which also succeeds.
To retrieve the live content of the frame is, where I am currently stuck. I spend a while on researching this already, but I was not able to find an answer to my problem. Please let me know, if you need further information to answer my question. On manually calls of the webpage, all works as intended.

Addition:

I had already tried to use the "Wait Until Keyword Succeeds", one example:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   ${ElementSearchTime}  1s   Page Should Contain Element   ${XPath_PluginElement}
```

Another example:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   ${ElementSearchTime}  1s   Page Should Contain   You could still view your document
```

It unfortunately did not have the wanted result. For me it seems like if the firstly received code was not updated and the "Page Should Contain Element" might not be the keyword that should be used.

EDIT: Yes, I was correct. I should have used the "Current Frame Contains Element" keyword from the Selenium2Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using Wait Until Keyword Succeeds?  I felt a bit wrong and dirty using it in the past but I've been told by many others more experienced than me, that this is the way to go.  It also got me out of a pickled in a similar scenario to you where a user click generated a row collapse and javascript helped render anything we needed.  I'll post my own example when I get into work but here's a basic form from the builtin docs (http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) :

If the keyword does not succeed regardless of retries, this keyword fails. If the executed keyword passes, its return value is returned.

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds 2 min   5 sec   My keyword  argument
${result} = Wait Until Keyword Succeeds 3x  200ms   My keyword
```

All normal failures are caught by this keyword. Errors caused by invalid syntax, test or keyword timeouts, or fatal exceptions (caused e.g. by Fatal Error) are not caught.

Running the same keyword multiple times inside this keyword can create lots of output and considerably increase the size of the generated output files. Starting from Robot Framework 2.7, it is possible to remove unnecessary keywords from the outputs using --RemoveKeywords WUKS command line option.
Support for specifying retry as a number of times to retry is a new feature in Robot Framework 2.9. Since Robot Framework 2.9, variable errors are caught by this keyword.

***Real-world example as promised***

```
${row_link_state}=    Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute    ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/tbody/tr/td/a@class
Run Keyword If    '${row_link_state}' == '${TABLE_LINK_CLASS_COLLAPSED}'     Click Element    ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/tbody/tr/td/a
...    ELSE    Fail    The row link was not in the expected state
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/tbody/tr/td/div/p    10
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10s    5s    Element Should Be Visible    ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/tbody/tr/td/div/p
${paragraph_text}=    Get Text    ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/tbody/tr/td/div/p
Should Be Equal    ${STATIC_TABLE_ROW1_TEXT}    ${paragraph_text}
```

I'm aware the above code block looks pretty nasty.  Essentially it is checking a table row is in an expected state which is handled by javascript.  The link in question flicks its class between two values to depict its state.  If it's in the expected state, we click on the table row which causes it to expand and reveal its contents.  You will notice the Wait Until Page Contains is a bit obsolete but it was still a bit flakey, its presence seems to slow things down enough for it to give repeatable results.  The wait until keyword succeeds then ensures the text I want to use is visible on the page before I attempt to get it and use it as a variable.  It is the only way I was able to get the above working.

See if you have any success with the above, if you're having trouble, post the code and issues here and I'll help out.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have already tried the Wait Until Keyword Succeds keyword, it unforunately did not have the wanted effect.  I am going to add the code to the question. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The times you've set in your example wouldn't work too well, the first time is the total wait time, so in the documents example, it will wait a total of two minutes to find what you've set it to look for.  The second time is the interval, so again in the documents example, though it's waiting for two minutes, it's actively performing a check every 5seconds for what you've set it to look for.  I think you know this, just covering in more detail.  So what is ${ElementSearchTime} value?  Are you also sure your xpath is correct?

Comment: Have you set your tests to take a screenshot on failure?  If I were you I would go into debug mode and check what the page looks like when it's performing that check.  Can you provide more failure information on the examples you say don't work please?

Comment: Yes, I do have the screenshot, the correct error message is being shown (second example). The correct frame (the one that is completely blank on the beginning) is also selected. The javascript function dynamically writes into the frame, the correct text appears, but Robotframework does not find the text.So,as even the text is not being recognised,I did not go into much more research for the Element. I think when I can fix the text one, I would also be able to debug the Element one.Which kind of failure information I still could give, I am also not sure, I'll try to do some research and provide

Comment: I found the Solution, Instead of Page Should Contain, I used the Current Frame Contains keyword. Don't know how I could oversee that. Thank you a lot for your kind help that did put me back to the right direction.

Comment: No worries @Aldaris, I'm glad you resolved your issue, all by yourself as well which I'm sure is pretty satisfying :)

Sorry I wasn't more help but congratulations on solving your problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92159/discussion-between-aldaris-and-shicky).